# Anaconda As Python in Debian Linux Terminal

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, anaconda

I am working on a project in python on a Debian 8 VM. To work on the project further I need to install matplotlib 1.5.1. When I attempt to upgrade the current version (obtained through apt-get) or install I am told that I need freetype and png. When I go to install freetype using this link:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/freetype2.html

After installing and entering the proper commands, I go to try to install matplotlib again and receive the same error.

I tried to install Anaconda3 because it comes with freetype and basically every package that I need for my project. But after running the .sh file I was unable to change my python to use anaconda as the interpreter. How can I do this?

Thanks!

[UPDATE]
I am having to go into my anaconda3 file, then run `source bin/activate ~/anaconda3/` Is there anyway to create an alias that would do all this?

Comment: Add this to your `.bashrc` -> `alias name=source /path/to/conda`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first create a conda python environment:

```
/path/to/conda/bin/conda create --name myenv python=3
```

(see http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html)

When the environment has been created you simply activate it as follows:

```
/path/to/conda/bin/source activate myenv
```

Thereafter the system will run python from the conda environment you specified and not from the standard location.

Comment: Is there any way to do all of this each time I start a terminal?

Comment: If you put the "source activate myenv" bit into your bash_profile then the environment will set each time you start a window